# How can I grab the data from a Choice Site Column in Sharepoint using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, p-np

I am new to Sharepoint, and I am stuck on an issue. I am using PnP/PnPjs, and I am trying to get the choice fields from one of the site Columns. I have tried using SPWeb, etc, but there are issues with this in typescript. Is there a way I can import this or another way I can grab this data?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the following code snippet:

Get choice site column definition:

```
import { sp } from "sp-pnp-js";
      let web = sp.web;
      web.fields.getByTitle("testchoice").get().then(f => {

        console.log(f);
    });
```

Get choice site column value used in a list:

```
    web.lists.getByTitle("MyList").items.getById(2).get().then((item: any) => {
      console.log(item.testchoice);
  });
```

Reference:

[@pnp/sp/fields](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/fields/)

[@pnp/sp/items](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/items/)